# How to count requests per hour?

Tags: command-line, awk, logfile-analysis

I have access log file with data only per 1 day like:

```
10.2.21.120 "-" - [26/Jan/2013:19:15:11 +0000] "GET /server/ad?uid=abc&type=PST HTTP/1.1" 202 14 10
10.2.21.120 "-" - [26/Jan/2013:19:17:22 +0000] "GET /server/ad?uid=abc&type=PST HTTP/1.1" 204 14 9
10.2.22.130 "-" - [26/Jan/2013:19:27:53 +0000] "GET /server/ad?uid=abc&type=PST HTTP/1.1" 200 14 8
```

I am using the following command:

```
awk '$9 == 200 { s++ } END { print s / NR * 100; }' access.log
```

Comment: In your example date fields the time zone is always `+00`, is it possible to have different time zones or the logging used just UTC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This awk may help you

```
$ awk -F[:\ ]  '{count[$5]++}; $12 == 200 { hour[$5]++} END { for (i in hour) print i, hour[i]/count[i]*100 }' input
```

**Test**

```
$ cat input
10.1.20.123 "1.1.1.1" - [15/Oct/2014:12:14:17 +0000] "POST /server/ad?uid=abc&type=PST HTTP/1.1" 200 3014 10
10.1.20.123 "1.1.1.1" - [15/Oct/2014:12:14:17 +0000] "POST /server/ad?uid=abc&type=PST HTTP/1.1" 100 3014 10
10.1.20.123 "1.1.1.1" - [15/Oct/2014:13:14:26 +0000] "POST /server/ad?uid=abc&type=PST HTTP/1.1" 200 3014 9
10.1.20.123 "1.1.1.1" - [15/Oct/2014:13:24:55 +0000] "POST /server/ad?uid=abc&type=PST HTTP/1.1" 200 3014 8
$  awk -F[:\ ]  '{count[$5]++}; $12 == 200 { hour[$5]++} END { for (i in hour) print i, hour[i]/count[i]*100 }' input
12 50
13 100
```

**What it does**

- `{count[$5]++}` array `count` stores the number of occurence of each hour from the log file.
- `$12 == 200 { hour[$5]++}` Now it the log is success, that is `$12 == 200` then the corresponding value in `hour` array is incremented.

  So `count[13]` will contain total enteries from hour `13` where as `hour[13]` would contain count of succuessfull entries
- `END { for (i in hour) print i, hour[i]/count[i]*100 }` prints the `hour, percentage`

Comment: Almost the same answer within few seconds, this time I was a bit fater :D

Comment: @fedorqui :D +1 for you. should i remove the answer?

Comment: They are pretty much alike, but yours has some different insights. So what *I* would do is to write a description of the logic you applied to it, because maybe it is more useful to the OP than mine. The more answers, the better to give knowledge to the site. +1 for you too!

Comment: @fedorqui will add a description to the answer :)

Comment: Please, don't remove your answer)

Comment: @SergeyI. Hehe I was about the remove the answer though :P Glad to hear that it helped you !!!!

Comment: Anyway to sort output hours? @nu11p01n73R my output is https://i.imgur.com/FdLJKpQ.png unsorted.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this:

```
awk -F"[ :]" '
    {tot[$5]++; if ($(NF-2)==200) succ[$5]++}
    END {for (i in tot) printf "%d %d/%d %.2f%\n", i, succ[i], tot[i], succ[i]/tot[i]*100}' file
```

This defines `:` or space as field separators. Hence, the hour is stored in the 5th field and the return code in the one before the penultimate (`NF-2`) - we could also use the 12th as you do, but this allows support for longest input in the log.

Then, it keeps track of the amount of lines in the `tot[]` array and the successful ones in `succ[]` array.

Finally it prints the result

---

Here we have some more data with different hours and return codes:

```
$ cat a
10.1.20.123 "1.1.1.1" - [15/Oct/2014:13:14:17 +0000] "POST /server/ad?uid=abc&type=PST HTTP/1.1" 200 3014 10
10.1.20.123 "1.1.1.1" - [15/Oct/2014:13:14:26 +0000] "POST /server/ad?uid=abc&type=PST HTTP/1.1" 200 3014 9
10.1.20.123 "1.1.1.1" - [15/Oct/2014:13:24:55 +0000] "POST /server/ad?uid=abc&type=PST HTTP/1.1" 100 3014 8
10.1.20.123 "1.1.1.1" - [15/Oct/2014:17:24:55 +0000] "POST /server/ad?uid=abc&type=PST HTTP/1.1" 200 3014 8
10.1.20.123 "1.1.1.1" - [15/Oct/2014:17:24:55 +0000] "POST /server/ad?uid=abc&type=PST HTTP/1.1" 404 3014 8
```

Let's run the script:

```
$ awk -F"[ :]" '{tot[$5]++; if ($(NF-2)==200) succ[$5]++} END {for (i in tot) printf "%d %d/%d %.2f%\n", i, succ[i], tot[i], succ[i]/tot[i]*100}' a
13 2/3 66.67%
17 1/2 50.00%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% cat success.awk
NF==11{
    split($4,a,":") ; hour = a[2]
    total[hour] += 1
    if($9==200) success[hour] += 1
    }
END{
    for(h in total) print h, 100*(0+success[h])/total[h]"% ("0+success[h]"/"total[h]")"
    }
% awk -f success.awk mylog
13 66.6667% (2/3)
17 50% (1/2)
%
```